# User Select CRS Tool

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, proj4js

I am trying to create a tool which lets the user select a Coordinate Reference System from a list to project their data to. Are there any available libraries (preferably JS), datasets, or API's which provide a list of CRS' that I can populate a dropdown with alongside the algorithm to use for the projection?

Comment: Proj library is delivered with an SQLite database called "proj.db". That contains all the data from the EPSG database and a bit more. Find details from https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/tree/master/data/sql. Maybe you could utilize it.

Comment: You could use [epsg.io](https://github.com/maptiler/epsg.io) API.